# Node.js Q promise forEach returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, q

Using Q for Node.js, I am promising a HTTP request, and upon fulfillment calling another function passing in the response of that HTTP request, that function then iterates over a JSON array from the HTTP requests, builds up  a new array, and returns it.

Debugging `Reddit.prototype.parseData` I can see the HTTP JSON is passed in, and within the for statement I can console.log `data` as it's been built, but at the end of the foreach I cannot console.log, or return the data object, it returns undefined

Reddit.js

```
var Reddit = function(){
    this.endpoint = "https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/hot.json?limit=10";
}

Reddit.prototype.parseData = function(json, q){
    var dataLength  = json.data.children.length,
        data        = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= dataLength; i++){
        var post    = {};

        post.url    = json.data.children[i].data.url;
        post.title  = json.data.children[i].data.title;
        post.score  = json.data.children[i].data.score;

        console.log(data); //returns data    

        data.push(post);
    }

    console.log(data); // returns undefined

    return data;
}

module.exports = Reddit;
```

Feeds.js

```
var https   = require('https'),
        q       = require('q'),
        Reddit  = require('./sources/reddit');

var Feeds = function(){
    this.reddit = new Reddit();
    console.log(this.parseRedditData()); //undefined
}

Feeds.prototype.getData = function(endpoint){
    var deferred = q.defer();

    https.get(endpoint, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
           deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

Feeds.prototype.parseRedditData = function(){
    var _this      = this;

    this.getData(this.reddit.endpoint).then(function(data){
        return _this.reddit.parseData(data);
    });


}

var fe = new Feeds()
```

Comment: Your `parseRedditData` method will always be undefined because it doesn't return anything. You will see the results you're expecting (assuming there are no other errors in your code) by logging the `data` variable when the `getData` promise is resolved.

Comment: Updated code to return something from the promise, the `data` variable on the getData promise is the result of the http request?

Comment: As an aside, you should be using the `<` operator in `for(var i = 0; i <= dataLength; i++)` in `Reddit.prototype.parseData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sholanozie said, you aren't returning anything from `parseRedditData`. I'm guessing what you want is:

```
var Feeds = function(){
    this.reddit = new Reddit();
    this.parseRedditData().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
...
Feeds.prototype.parseRedditData = function(){
    var _this      = this;

    return this.getData(this.reddit.endpoint).then(function(data){
        return _this.reddit.parseData(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay so I see this working now, however, I still get nothing returned from my console.log on line 9 of Feeds.js, is there anything I need to do in Reddit.js?

Comment: Are you referring to this part of the `Feed` constructor: `this.parseRedditData().then(function(data) { console.log(data); });`?

Comment: Yes, the console.log(data); returns nothing in this instance and the promise not fulfilled function is running.

Comment: You probably have an error in `Reddit.parseData` somewhere. You can debug with `this.parseRedditData().fail(function(err) { console.error(err.stack); });`.